# What is the difference between listViewAdapter.clear() and list.clear()?

Tags: android, listview

Okay, I think I have understood it, but I just want to make sure of it. I have got a ListViewAdapter that contains a List.What I wanna do is search thinks in the database and show in a ListView. This piece of code adds an item to my listView.

```
list.addAll(sqh.DisplayRecords(sqdb));
    listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           listViewAdapter.clear();

           list.clear();
           list.addAll(sqh.DisplayRecords(sqdb));
           list.add("another one");

        }
    });
```

Whit this other piece of code, only clearing the listviewAdapter and adding another item to the list, just, adds the last item, instead of all the items of the list, which should be there.

```
        list.addAll(sqh.DisplayRecords(sqdb));
    listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter( this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listViewAdapter.clear();

            list.add("another one");

        }
    });
```

Well, I think I understood it while I was writing this. The third one and the first one are pretty the same.

```
list.addAll(sqh.DisplayRecords(sqdb));
    listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter( this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    listview.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listViewAdapter.clear();

            list.addAll(sqh.DisplayRecords(sqdb));
            list.add("another one");

        }
    });
```

The listViewAdapter.clear(); would be clearing the list of the adapter, right? Why, when I do just list.clear(), the list view is not cleared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you calling `list.clear();`, you'are removing all of the elements from the list. The list will be empty after this call returns. But your Adapter view isn't change yet. You need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the adapter.

In the other case, when you calling `listViewAdapter.clear();`, the list will be cleared first then the `notifyDataSetChanged()` called.

You can see the details in [`ArrayAdapter.clear()` source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L312):

```
/**
 * Remove all elements from the list.
 */
public void clear() {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mOriginalValues != null) {
            mOriginalValues.clear();
        } else {
            mObjects.clear();
        }
        mObjectsFromResources = false;
    }
    if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[listViewAdapter.clear()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear())**

> void clear ()
>
> Remove all elements from the list.

**And `list.clear();`**

```
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this list.  The list will
 * be empty after this call returns.
 */
public void clear() {
    modCount++;

    // clear to let GC do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    size = 0;
}
```

If you use in this , it was the same .It used to `Removes all of the elements from this list` .